# Как найти трэй программу через FindWindow?

Tags: winapi, delphi

Есть программа, при закрытии сворачивается в трэй. И ее не видит FindWindow. Как найти?

Comment: Описанное @Бегемот`ом, можно реализовать, пробежавсшись по всем окнам системы, используя WINAPI функцию - **EnumWindows()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программа, свернутая в трэй, имеет невидимое окно (окно без стиля `WS_VISIBLE`). Это окно можно найти с помощью FindWindow (FindWindowEx). Вы можете использовать программу Spy++, чтобы найти окно приложения (проще это делать, когда окно видимо) и параметры (например, ClassName), по которым надо искать через FindWindow.